# React: communicate between parent and child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to communicate from my Child component (a input form) to my parent component (popup) weather or not there is any data in the child.

The issue im facing is that the child component isn't a set child in the code it gets there with the `{props.children}` tag:

App.js structure:

```
<div>
   <Popup>
      </Child>
   </Popup>
</div>
```

Popup.js structure:

```
<div>
   {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without using a window.* variable or frankenstein-ing a stateSet/stateRead function in my App.js?

Comment: How do you expect to do state management of the form without state management of some kind? Pass down handlers to the child? Use Context? Use Recoil, or Redux?

Comment: I was hoping for a way to solve this issue within the pupup and child components without changing the app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some risky stuff here, but it gets the job done:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function NewApp() {
  return (
    <Parent pProps="boss">
      <Child text="Hello1" />
      <Child text="Hello2" />
      <Child text="Hello3" />
    </Parent>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

  function communicateWithMe(val) {
    console.log("I am called", val);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let _children = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
      console.log("Parent child", child);
      return {
        ...child,
        props: {
          ...child.props,
          callBack: communicateWithMe
        }
      };
    });

    console.log("_children", _children);
    setChildren(_children);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        background: "black",
        color: "white"
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
      {props.callBack && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            props.callBack("children baby");
          }}
        >
          invoke Parent function
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the sandbox version to see it in action:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wood-5kuit3?file=/NewApp.js

Explaination:

What I aimed to do was to append the props on the children from the parent component. To do that, I casted the children (received in props by Parent) in to local state.
Appended the prop to each child to have a callback function to communicate with the parent.
The Parent component now returns the state variable that has the modified / appended props, instead of returns prop.children as it received!

EDIT:

As suggested, I have used React.Children to iterate over the children recieved by the parent in props.

Comment: Use `React.Children`. Don't iterate over `children`directly.

Comment: Thanks I just did that. let me edit the snippet in the answer!

Comment: that is pretty much exactly what i was looking for thanks